# what is the secret of eliminating black string between UINavigationbar and another view by using following method?

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

i have UINavigationbar and view underneath it.[image]

and when i am saying following instructions the string is disappeared

```
   UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
   UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage( UIImage(), for: 
  .default)
```

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation it looks like once you set setBackgroundImage it overrides the shadowImage with your custom implementation. On the navigation bar check out shadowImage it says:

"/* **Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of the default shadow image.** For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: (**if the default background image is used, the default shadow image will be used**).
 */

@property(nullable, nonatomic,strong) UIImage *shadowImage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;"

So you are overriding the default with a blank image which in turns removes the default shadow or string as you call it.

Comment: if a understand you correctly when i set backgroundimage with blank view then shadowimage removes because of setting blank view to the backgroundimage property?

Comment: because of view is transparent?

Comment: the default view has the shadow effect to it. When you are implementing your own custom view, it removes that line or "string" because it is trying to implement your custom view. But in your case you are saying that the custom view is just a blank UIView instance and nothing more. If your UIView had more to it and defined additional content, it would show that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please tell us where the string is placed?

It could be string is same color as background color.

We can debug whether string is actually present in UI hierarchy using debug inspector with show clipped content enabled (which helps us to know any clipped views are present). I've attached screenshot for your reference.

[View inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKp91.png)

Comment: this string is underneath home button and i am not using storyboard

Comment: Can you please elaborate it. The string which you're talking about is navigation title ?